# Multiplying numbers using windowing functions for conditional Probability in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, conditional-statements, probability, windowing

I have a hive table that looks like this

```
id, index, p
1, 1, 0.2 
1, 2, 0.1 
1, 3, 0.3 
1, 4, 0.1 
2, 1, 0.2 
2, 2, 0.3 
2, 3, 0.4
```

For each `id`, I want to calculate the following:

```
\sum_{i=1}^n(\prod _{k=1}^{i-1}(1-p_k))
```

[image]

For instance, for `id=2`, this would be `p_1 + (1-p_1)*p2 + (1-p_1)*(1-p_2)*p3` since it only has three probabilities. Is there a way to do this in Hive using windowing functions?

Comment: hi ahoosh, what is p_1?

Comment: `p_1` is probability associated with `index=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using product with windowing, partitioning by id and ordering by index. I'm not sure if there is an aggregate function for product, but if not, one can make use of log+sum+exp to get the same effect.

```
with table1 as (
    select *, 
    sum(log(1-p)) over(partition by id order by index rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as log_sum
    from source_table
)
select id, sum(p*coalesce(exp(log_sum), 1)) as p_prod_q_prior
from table1
group by id
```